# Jquery or javascript to show hidden text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to turn this:

```
Item1 ShowMore<br>
Item2 ShowMore<br>
Item3 ShowMore<br>
```

Into

```
Item1 hidden text<br>
Item2 more hidden text<br>
Item3 even more text<br>
```

So I need to show that hidden text, in line, when i click on ShowMore, and the ShowMore has to disappear when pressed.

Also i have hundreds of lines where i will use this, and I wander if there is an way to accomplish this without giving a unique id to each element.

I found an posible solution here, but it does the opposite thing, it hides the text... http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=49205 (second post)

Comment: Please, show us some code of yours, so we could improve it.

Comment: sorry, it looked fine in the editor, and i didn't checked the preview...

Comment: This question is too vague. How do you know what the hidden text is? Provide html. Provide how you tried to do this with javascript or jquery and tell us what errors you got you don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Hope you are looking for this..

**Html**

```
<p>Blablabla1 <span class="showhide">ShowMore</span> Blablabla2 <span class="showhide">ShowMore</span> Blablabla3 <span class="showhide">ShowMore</span></p>
```

**CSS**

```
.showhide {
    color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

**Script**

```
$(".showhide").click(function () {
    if ($(this).text() == "ShowMore") {
        $(this).text("HiddenText");
    } else {
        $(this).text("ShowMore");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/568geaya/)

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/568geaya/1/)

Comment: All this does is change some hard coded button text...how does this answer question?

Comment: Yeah, after i test it a little more i noticed the same thing... Raoulito's solution works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

There are hundreds of ways to make a function for this. You could make it really simple if you write your codes in a clever way.

Here's one example: https://jsfiddle.net/3250pzbz/

HTML:

```
First sentance: <em>Show More</em><span class="hidden">That's a hidden sentance.</span>
Second sentance: <em>Show More</em><span class="hidden">That's another hidden sentance.</span>
Third sentance: <em>Show More</em><span class="hidden">And so on…</span>
```

and the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.hidden').hide(); // 1. hide all elements with class="hidden"
    $('em').click(function(){ // 2. when click on any <em>
        $(this).hide().next('.hidden').show(); // 3. hide the em you clicked on — 4. show the next element with class="hidden"
    });
});
```

I advise you to post examples of your code and people here will be able to help you much more precisely.